# Flex dataGrid columns missing header text

Tags: apache-flex, text, datagrid, header

I created a component that is multiple datagrids side by side that share the same columns (each datagrid is the same as the one before but with different data).

**Problem**

The header text only shows up on the last datagrid.  How can I get the text to show up on all the datagrid headers?

Here is how I instantiate the component.

```
    <common:PageDataGrid width="100%" height="100%"
        numGroups="5" numRows="9" dataProvider="{createData(5, 9)}">
        <common:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="ext" headerText="EXT." width="45"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="name" headerText="ASSIGNED TO"/>
        </common:columns>
    </common:PageDataGrid>
```

Here is how I am creating the datagrids

```
        for(var i:uint=0; i < _numGroups; i++)
        {
            dataGrid = new DataGrid();
            dataGrid.headerHeight = 25;
            dataGrid.rowCount = _numRows;
            dataGrid.rowHeight = 25;
            dataGrid.percentWidth = 100;
            dataGrid.dataProvider = dataGridProviders.getItemAt(i);

            dataGrid.columns = this._columns;

            dataGrid.addEventListener(DataGridEvent.HEADER_RELEASE, onHeaderRelease);

            this.addChild(dataGrid);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to do a deep copy of the datagridcolumns before I assigned them to the datagird.  Here is what I needed to do.

```
        for(var i:uint=0; i < _numGroups; i++)
        {
            dataGrid = new DataGrid();
            dataGrid.headerHeight = 25;
            dataGrid.rowCount = _numRows;
            dataGrid.rowHeight = 25;
            dataGrid.percentWidth = 100;
            dataGrid.dataProvider = dataGridProviders.getItemAt(i);

            // Deep Copy        
            registerClassAlias("mx.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridColumn", DataGridColumn);
            var columnsCopy:Array = new Array(this._columns.length);
            for(var j:uint=0; j < this._columns.length; j++)
            {
                columnsCopy[j] = ObjectUtil.copy(this._columns[j]) as DataGridColumn;
            }
            // End Deep Copy
            dataGrid.columns = columnsCopy;

            dataGrid.addEventListener(DataGridEvent.HEADER_RELEASE, onHeaderRelease);

            this.addChild(dataGrid);
        }
```